# Ticks with euro symbol in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, ascii

I am trying to plot having one of the axis Euro units.
The function I am formatting is:

```
def money(x, pos):
    return '$%1.0fB' % (x*1e-9)
```

and it works well with $. Now I need to interchange $ with € symbol, which is not directly recognized.

what I tried is:

```
def money(x, pos):
    return r'$\euro$%1.0fB' % (x*1e-9)
```

but the terminal says:

```
Unknown symbol: \euro
```

Comment: Charset/UTF-8 issue?

Comment: `'€%1.0fB' % (x*1e-9)` works fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can additionally also try using `\texteuro` as

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('text', usetex=True)

plt.plot(range(5))
plt.xlabel(r'\texteuro%1.0fB')
plt.show()
```

[image]